# How to implement API security for local and remote requests?

Tags: web-services, api, security, encryption

I have setup an web-based API to allow a remote app to GET/POST data. Every API call is authenticated with a User ID and Password that is encrypted with a secret key known only to the remote app and the website. This authentication not only ensures that the user can access the API, but also allows me to implement security features based on the user's profile (i.e. User A can see items A & B, but not item C).

I would like my server-side website pages to be able to call the same API methods remotely via AJAX calls, but, something just doesn't seem right about storing encrypted passwords in the code, and, my website implements a "Login As" feature, which will not allow me to set the encrypted password, since the passwords are not stored in plain text.

What is a good way to implement API security for both remote and "local" calls that doesn't require encrypting the user's password?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be storing usernames and passwords in server side code. Sooner or later someone will lay eyes on your code and your data will be vulnerable.

But you should also not be storing secrets (key) in client side code. You should not assume your client can be trusted to keep that secret.

Giving user A access to item A and B, but not C is called authorization and depends on you knowing who calls your API (authentication).

You should probably look into a authentication protocol like [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) and an authorization protocol like [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/).

Also see my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219923/where-to-place-login-dialog-for-3-legged-auth-for-restful-api/27240429#27240429) question.

Comment: Just to clarify, there are no secret keys stored-viewable client-side, nor are password stored in plain-text anywhere.

Comment: Even if you store them encrypted on the client side, if the client can decrypt, then so can an attacker. Security tokens are safer as they are only valid for a limited amount of time and eliminate the need to store secrets in the client.

Comment: Isn't OpenId or Oauth overkill for a simple AJAX call?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you have both a native client and a browser client. Both flows are supported in OAuth2. I'd rather opt for authentication based on well-known protocols than implement my own.